# The local farm is not accessible

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

When I run SharePoint PowerShell on my SharePoint server I get the following error:

Error: `"The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered".`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the logged in user has rights to configuration database.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20399.sharepoint-2013-the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered.aspx